# What exactly is the philosophy behind sending blessings and prayer to our prophet in case of Allah and the angels?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, malaikah, salawat, blessings-of-allah

Allah ordered us to send prayers and blessings to our prophet () saying:

> Indeed, Allah confers blessing upon the Prophet, and His angels [ask Him to do so]. O you who have believed, ask [ Allah to confer] blessing upon him and ask [ Allah to grant him] peace.([33:56](http://legacy.quran.com/33/56))

from the sunnah we know the rewards and wording for those who do perform this deed.

But what exactly is the case for Allah and the angels when they sent prayers and blessing to our prophet ()? Is there a benefit for Allah in doing this, I might assume that there is for the angels at least ... so my question might be why and how is Allah doing this then and how and what is the deeper meaning or the philosophy behind this???

Comment: What makes you think Allah gets benifit from doing anything? Let alone sending salawaat on the Prophet (SAW). Allah does things because he wishes. Not for benifit.

Comment: @TheZ nothing I just want to know whether or what scholars have some explanation for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ibn Kathir introduced this saying:

> Al-Bukhari said: "Abu Al-'Aliyah said: **"Allah's Salah is His praising him before the angels, and the Salah of the angels is their supplication**." Ibn 'Abbas said: "They send blessings." Abu 'Isa At-Tirmidhi said: "This was narrated from Sufyan Ath-Thawri and other scholars, who said: 'The **Salah of the Lord is mercy, and the Salah of the angels is their seeking forgiveness**. (Source [qtafsir](http://m.qtafsir.com/Surah-Al-Ahzab/The-Command-to-say-Salah-upon----))

Ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani considerd the interpretation given by Abu al-'Aliyah [أبو العالية الرياحي](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AD%D9%8A) as the best on this topic.
This gives an answer about the kind of blessings and prayers. Unfortunatley the authors of qtafsir didn't go further in their translation and didn't address the deeper meaning:
(<sub>Note whenever I quote Arabic text the English translation is of my own and should be taken with care!</sub>)

> والمقصود من هذه الآية : أن الله سبحانه أخبر عباده بمنزلة عبده ونبيه عنده في الملأ الأعلى ، بأنه يثني عليه عند الملائكة المقربين ، وأن الملائكة تصلي عليه . ثم أمر تعالى أهل العالم السفلي بالصلاة والتسليم عليه ، ليجتمع الثناء عليه من أهل العالمين العلوي والسفلي جميعا .  ([Tafsir ibn Kathir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1502&idto=1502&bk_no=49&ID=1537))
> And what is meant by this verse is the following: Allah Exalted is He informed in this verse his servants about the high rank of his servant and prophet with Him and His exalted assembly (of angels). That he praises him with his favourite (closest) angels and that the angels send prayers to him. Then He Exalted is He ordered the people of the lower world to send prayers and blessings to him. To gather both praising from the lower and upper world together.

That's why Allah() says:

> And raised high for you your repute ([94:4](http://legacy.quran.com/94/4))

So the prayers and blessings mean:

> “Blessings upon the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)” – according to the majority of scholars, what is meant is mercy from Allaah, prayers for forgiveness offered by the angels, and du’aa’ offered by humans. (Source: islamqa #[69944](https://islamqa.info/en/69944))

Imam al-Qurtobi -in [his tafsir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=48&surano=33&ayano=56)- introduced the verse similarly to ibn Kathir  saying:

> هذه الآية شرف الله بها رسوله عليه السلام حياته وموته ، وذكر منزلته منه ، وطهر بها سوء فعل من استصحب في جهته فكرة سوء ، أو في أمر زوجاته ونحو ذلك . والصلاة من الله رحمته ورضوانه ، ومن الملائكة الدعاء والاستغفار ، ومن الأمة الدعاء والتعظيم لأمره .
> This verse is a honouring of Allah for his Prophet peace be upon him in his life and death and a mentioning of his rank with Allah, and is a cleaning for every evil deed of those who carry any idea of evil towards him, or about his wives <sup>(*)</sup> and likewise, and the prayer from Allah is (His) mercy and (His acceptance and from the angels is supplication (du'a) and seeking forgivness and from the Ummah is supplication and high esteem for him.

<sup>(*) Allah mentioned the wives of the prophet in the context of this verse, in the verses before and later! Note that the same applies to verse ([33:33](http://legacy.quran.com/33/33)) which calls them ahl al-Bayt.</sup>

Finally note that Arabic world for prayer الصلاة (as-Salah) has a link to the word الصلة (as-Sillah) the connection. And via du'a we are in connection with Allah: We make a supplication and he listen and answers it.

Maybe adding the word "benefit" was a bit misleading, of course Allah doesn't benefit from praising any of his creations be it our prophet () nor actually do the angels as they are following the orders of Allah.

As to the why I think it is clear that Allah's praising means that our prophet has a high rank with Allah.

As to the how it is explained in the couple of quotes above.

Answer (score 1):

Allah (ﷻ) said:

> فاذكروني أذكركم ("**remember Me, I will remember you**") - [Qur'an 2:152](https://quran.com/2/152).

This applies to everyone, including the Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ). He would remember Allah (ﷻ) often (more than anyone else who ever lived) and as promised, Allah (ﷻ) remembered him as a result by conferring blessings upon him.

Not just that, but the Prophet (ﷺ) said:

> “Allah, the Most High said: ‘I am as My slave thinks of Me, and I am with him when he remembers Me. If he remembers Me to himself, I remember him to Myself, and if he remembers Me in a gathering, **I remember him in a gathering better than that**... - [Tirmidhi (3603)](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/234).

Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) remembered Allah (ﷻ) at every gathering in his entire lifetime since Prophethood, in front of crowds of people. Per the hadith, Allah (ﷻ) would then remember him in a gathering better than that. So how did Allah (ﷻ) do this?

Answer: Allah (ﷻ) ordered the Believers to ask for blessings upon him; ordered this in the Qur'an which would then be read by Believers for centuries after his passing and they would continue to ask Allah (ﷻ) to bless him. SubhanAllah. Who is truer than Allah (ﷻ) in keeping His Promise?!

P.S. **Nothing "benefits" Allah (ﷻ)**. It is part of Tawheed to understand this so I hope you do. Allah (ﷻ) does things for specific 'reasons' but nothing is for His benefit, rather it is all for the benefit of His creation.

Comment: This looks like a good part of the answer!

Answer (score -3):

When we send prayers and blessings to our prophet, we get Hasanat. you should notice that we get them primarily for obeying Allah's order.

The case for Allah and the angels:

*In fact,* Allah does not get any benefit from our doings at all. 
For example, when we pray and say Allahu-Akbar "Allah is the Greatest", this does not make Allah greater, because he is already the Greatest.
The benefit of any deed comes to us. Praying enables us to talk to Allah and ask him to give us what we want, zakat is beneficial for our society to clear poverty, and sending prayers and blessings to Muhammad is beneficial for us that we continuously remember our prophet and do as he does, and try to act like him. (peace be upon him).

As for the Angels: Angels are created only with one specific order, to obey Allah at everything.
The benefit they get for obeying Allah's order is that they remain angels and don't enter hell. *In fact*, Satan (the Devil) was a jinn, but he disobeyed Allah when he ordered him to kneel for Adam ... (you know the story). So Allah promised him that he will enter hell for eternity along with those who disbelieve in Allah.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam, To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. As to your answer: I don't see how this answers my question!