# Hadith explaination and grade

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

Salam, recently  I came across a Hadith which has been troubling me this hadith is found in the Riyadh as-saliheen a book by Imam Al-Nawawi. Which is as follows:

Abu Umamah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "The superiority of the learned over the devout worshipper is like my superiority over the most inferior amongst you (in good deeds)." He went on to say, "Allah, His angels, the dwellers of the heaven and the earth, and even the ant in its hole and the fish (in water) supplicate in favour of those who teach people knowledge."

[At-Tirmidhi].
http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/13/12

The last part says that Allah and His creation supposedly prays in favour of those people which doesn't make sense like why would Allah supplicate?

Can someone explain how to understand this hadith properly or is it mistranslated? if so then what is the correct translation?

Comment: This could be similar to the case of verse (33:56) see for example [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/48325/13438).

Comment: That I understand but is there any sharh of this particular hadith?

Comment: I'd assume, the question is whether there's a hadith interpretation addressing this point in particular. This is - based on my experience so far- ehat could be an issue. Sometimes hadith interpreters consider a few facts, as known an don't address them. However in the given case I'd assume they would have addressed it somehow.

Comment: So,the prayer of Allah is understood as mercy and blessings of Allah upon the creation?If so then that does answer my question. But is there any explanation by scholars about this hadith addressing the particular point? I tried searching online there are sharh books on the Riyadh as-salihin on the particular chapter of book of knowledge but I need to buy them.